Making Sense of the Dates for Coretime, Fixing Terminology
I am trying to make sense of the dates expressed in different ways. I cannot reconcile right now the dates shown on RegionX with my own calculations.

There are several terms flying around which overlap. For example: the renewals phase has an interlude length, suggesting that the phase could also be called "interlude".
The "Sale" only starts with the Price Discovery Phase, which has a "leading length", suggesting it could also be called the "leading phase". I have also seen the term "leadin" used in the event metadata. (Very likely the diagram should also say 'leadin')
On chain config says interlude is 50400 blocks, which is 7 days, since we are using coretime parachain blocks.
Leadin is 100800 blocks, which is 14 days.
Region X says the sale started on 2024-09-19, which is consistent with an event firing SalesStarted -- only the naming is unfortunate, since only renewals have started then.
The SalesInitialized event has sale start = 151388, which is also expressed in coretime blocks and therefore calculates as 2024-09-26. This is when "proper" sales start.
When I calculate the "Region Begin" I get 2024-10-09, which is before the Sales is supposed to end. This does not make sense!
How do I calculate a date from region? I divide region by 180 and add the number of days to the genesis date. This is consistent with the duration 28 days from begin to end.
Could an expert here help figure out the problem?
(Question edited with new info)

To answer this question properly I'll first demonstrate the link between some relevant terms to calendar units (for the polkadot config).
As Szegoo correctly noted, the timing will soon be defined solely by the Relay Chain block number as clock. This will hopefully make these things more intuitive.
Sale period:

Timeslice - 80 Relay Chain blocks long, 80*6 = 480 seconds.
Interlude - the period of time between sales on the open market. Region sales still happen in this period in the form of renewals. Length: 7 days (interlude_length in broker.configuration in Coretime Chain blocks ~12s).
Lead-in period - (yes, "leading" is a typo on that figure) is the period in which the sale price starts at a high price and drops linearly in two phases - steeply for 7 days and then less steeply for a further 7 days. Length: 14 days starting at the end of the interlude (leadin_length in broker.configuration in Coretime Chain blocks ~12s)
Fixed price period - Note this has no fixed length, and actually the end of this period is defined by the start of the next period, not a number of Coretime Chain blocks since the end of the lead-in length. If the Coretime Chain blocks were produced with no time drift, then this would be 7 days.
Region length - the definitive time in Relay Chain blocks which defines the length of a region sold by the system, as well as the length of the sale period (interlude, lead-in and fixed price periods). This is measured in timeslices, which consist of 80 Relay Chain blocks (region_length in broker.configuration in timeslices)
Region begin - the first timeslice of the next region. This is relevant as it is the start of the regions sold in the current sale period, but also because it is the timeslice at which the current sale will be rotated and the new sale will begin. This is exactly 5040 timeslices after the previous region's start timeslice.

The timestamp you have marked on the figure is incorrect, the region_begin unit is timeslices, which are 80 Relay Chain blocks long. It should be the timestamp of Relay Chain block 287565*80 =23005200, which is 2024-10-17 11:19:32.
A note on clocking: the Coretime Chain is a parachain with a nominal block production period of 12s, however parachain block times drift considerably more than the Relay Chain, and as with any two drifting clocks they must be synced. In this case we sync at the start of a region, as determined by the Relay Chain block, as I said before, this is the more regular clock of the two, and also is the defining measurement of a region's start and length (Region length is measured in timeslices, which in turn are defined as being 80 Relay Chain blocks long). Note that the Relay Chain has some drift from the nominal 6 seconds too, and over time this can lead to calendar timestamps being off unless they're synced.
What this means in practice is that each sale period starts (with the interlude) at the Coretime Chain block corresponding to the start block of the region begin timeslice.
Then the interlude is 7 days, where teams can renew their lease or existing bulk coretime purchase, then the lead-in period runs for 14 days, followed by the fixed price period until the start of the next region.
On the SalesStarted event - this shows that the Coretime Chain has gone from its initial state essentially just tracking the Relay Chain core assigments in terms of parachains that are reserved, leased and the end of those leases. The naming shows that we go from the state where no sales are run to the cyclic sales beginning. The interlude is very much part of the sale period, despite not offering cores on the open market.
Calculating the date from a region can be done using two quantities: the timestamp of a known block (ref_block_number) and the timeslice, which can be used to estimate the number of seconds after that known timestamp with timeslice * 80 * 6 - ref_block_number. Due to block production time variations I'd suggest using a recent block instead of the genesis date.
I hope this answers all your questions. If you have any follow ups I'd be happy to answer them.

sale_start, interlude_length, and leadin_length are defined in parachain blocks, not in relay chain blocks. Therefore, 100800 refers to parachain blocks, where the block time is 12 seconds.
This explains why you received half of the actual value for each duration, as you calculated them assuming a block time of 6 seconds. There is currently a PR in progress that will switch from using parachain blocks to relay chain blocks, which will make things more intuitive: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/5656
Sale cycles have the same duration as a region(assuming it hasn't been partitioned). When calculating a region start, you can simply use the interlude start for the upcoming cycle(which basically represents the end date of the current sale cycle). As shown in your question, the sale end date is the same as the region start date, which proves my point.

I won't be giving up on converting regions to dates. Our policy is to use event data as much as possible, and almost everything seems to be expressed in regions.
Region related to Sale 1: starts on 287565=2024-10-09 15:36
This seems to be before the sales actually end, so I still need to understand why this inconsistency arises.
Also, using the Interlude of an upcoming sales cycle seems counter intuitive since it may not have fired yet
